ImportError: cannot import name 'DETECTORS' from 'mmdet.models'
cannot import name 'DETECTORS' from 'mmdet.models'. I have installed mmdet version 3.2.0, mmcv version 2.1.0 and mmdet3d version 1.3.0.
I can't solve this problem. I tried everything but it didn't work. Even I tried to downgrade all of them, the problem was still there. So, please give me some solution to my problem

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
